# How to send a date values to the constructor through object and how to get that date values back?

Tags: java

> when I want to compile the below code compile-time error says: the
> constructor Person(String, int ) is undefined, etc...
>
> Person p = new Person("abhi",2/4/2019);

I wrote this code:

```
import java.util.Date;

class Person{
    String name;
    Date DOB;
    public Person(String name, Date dOB) {
        this.name = name;
        DOB = dOB;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Date getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }
}

class Student extends Person
{
    int StudentID; 
    public Student(String name, Date dOB, int studentID) {
        super(name, dOB);
        StudentID = studentID;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return StudentID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person("abhi",2/4/2019); // i can't pass date values to constructor
        student s = new Student("mark",2019-04-01,123456); //i can't pass date values to constructor
        System.out.println("Name "+p.getName());
        System.out.println("DOB  "+p.getDOB());
        System.out.println("Name  "+s.getName());
        System.out.println("DOB  "+s.getDOB());
        System.out.println("StudID  "+s.getStudentID());
    }
}
`
```

Comment: I believe you should be more specific.
But i can suggest you to take a look at ```Consumer``` class you can pass into constructor. Or you can save value into field and take it back once your pojo is initialised

Comment: you could use getter and setter to set and return the values. For passing the date, try to make a custom constructor to send in the date value and set them (as in Class c = new Class(PassDateHere);). Do you have some minimal code you might have worked on ?

Comment: Could you provide some code? And perhaps an explanation about your code too? This question is a little too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `2/4/2019` is interpreted as an integer division (2 divided by 4 divided by 2019), i.e. 0. But it's definitely not a date.

Instead of using a `Date` object, I suggest using [a `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) which is easier to use. Your code would then become:

```
Person p = new Person("abhi", LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 2));
```